# A question of style: LINQ or XPath to read in XML nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I am interested to know how to read the following XML in the most elegant / cleanest way possible.
(snippet)

```
<Config>
    <MyTag />
    <MyTag />
</Config>
<Config>
    <MyTag />
    <MyTag />
    <MyTag />
</Config>
```

I want to read in the `MyTag` nodes only. My first thought was LINQ but didn't know if it was cleaner using XPath.

Comment: Both work and are reasonable approaches. I'd use LINQ to XML, but your taste might be different. Choose what you like!

Comment: What's exactly elegant/cleanest?

Comment: I was just about to add a good answer including code and benchmarks.  Please reopen. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a lot cleaner to use XPath:

```
foreach(XElement myTag in (IEnumerable)XDocument.Load(xmlFile)
                                            .XPathEvaluate("/xml/Config/MyTag"))
{
}
```

The LINQ equivalent would be:

```
foreach(var myTag in XDocument.Load(xmlFile).Root.Elements("Config")
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("MyTag")))
{
}
```

My answer assumes that there is a `xml` tag around the `Config` tags, because otherwise the xml file wouldn't be valid.

Comment: I didnt know about `XPathEvaluate` it looks FAR cleaner than `XPathNaviagor` etc!

Comment: What type does `XPathEvaluate` return?

Comment: @Chris: Sorry, fixed the code.

Comment: @Chris - The XPath is a little easier to look at, but I wouldn't say that the Linq syntax is prohibitively complex.  And the Linq solution is going to be around 5X faster in this case.  I'd post my benchmarking results if this question hadn't been closed already.

Comment: @Steve: The "deeper" the XPath, the more complex the LINQ syntax

Answer (score 1):

You describe which tags you're after in the question so it might be a matter of style. But is it possible the query will be different in the future? That is, might the query be formed at run-time? I ask becuase XPath might be the way to go becuase it's a query string. LINQ can be very flexible but you do need to know more about the structure of the XML and the query to build an expression.

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net has (imo) the most elegant way :

```
Dim xml = <XML>
              <Config>
                  <MyTag>1</MyTag>
                  <MyTag>2</MyTag>
              </Config>
              <Config>
                  <MyTag>3</MyTag>
                  <MyTag>4</MyTag>
                  <MyTag>5</MyTag>
                  <MyTag>6</MyTag>
              </Config>
          </XML>
xml.Descendants("MyTag").ToList.ForEach(Sub(x)
                                            Console.WriteLine("MyTag = {0}", x.Value)
                                        End Sub)
Console.ReadLine()
```